# LWC - Convert Null values to empty string and Append field

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am working on an integration with Slack to Invite a SF User to a channel when they follow a Case.  Unfortunately the SF EntitySubscription Object does not support triggers so I needed to make my own custom Object, CaseFollow__c and replicate the logic.
I have created a "Follow" button on the Case which launches a LWC to insert a new CaseFollow_c record and appends the FollowUsers__c field on the Case with the running User. (I have a formula on the Case to check if the User ID is in the filed so I can display and hide the button)

The inset is working fine.  I am having problems trying to figure out the syntax to append the FollowUsers__c (Line 30).
Initially the FollowUsers__c field will be empty so I need would not want this to populate with  Null

```
import {LightningElement, api, wire} from 'lwc';
import {getRecord, getFieldValue, updateRecord, createRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

import field_case_Id from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Id';
import field_case_FollowUsers from '@salesforce/schema/Case.FollowUsers__c';

import object_CaseFollow from '@salesforce/schema/CaseFollow__c';
import field_follow_Case from '@salesforce/schema/CaseFollow__c.Case__c';
import field_follow_User from '@salesforce/schema/CaseFollow__c.User__c';

import field_RunningUserId from '@salesforce/user/Id';

const getfields = [field_case_FollowUsers];

export default class Case_InsertCaseFollow extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId
    
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', getfields })
    case;
    get followers() {
        //this.followers = (this.case.data ? getFieldValue(this.case.data, field_case_FollowUsers) : '');
        return getFieldValue(this.case.data, field_case_FollowUsers);
    }

    @api invoke(){     
        
        const updateFields = {}
            updateFields[field_case_Id.fieldApiName] = this.recordId
            updateFields[field_case_FollowUsers.fieldApiName] =  this.followers + ' ' + field_RunningUserId
        const updateInput = {fields:updateFields}
        updateRecord(updateInput)

        const createFields ={}
            createFields[field_follow_Case.fieldApiName] = this.recordId
            createFields[field_follow_User.fieldApiName] = field_RunningUserId
        let createInput = { apiName: object_CaseFollow.objectApiName, fields:createFields}
        createRecord(createInput).then(()=>{
            this.showToast("Success","Case Followed","success")             
        }).catch(error=>{
            //error handling
            this.showToast("Error",error.message,"error")
            })
        }

        showToast(title, message, variant){
        this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
            title, message, variant
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure I follow where you are facing issues. You are unable to add a null check and assign an empty string if it is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response.  I solved this using the following syntax

this.followers= getFieldValue(this.wiredCase.data, field_case_FollowUsers) ? getFieldValue(this.wiredCase.data, field_case_FollowUsers) : '';